# aos.js:122 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null

Tags: javascript

I Just started using AOS, seeing error in chrome console.
aos.js:122 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null

Comment: Can you share your code, please?

Answer (score 1):

You must initialize your AOS at the bottom of your body tag.

AOS.init({
        duration: 1200
    });